# Muscle spasm/contraction

Tags: muscle, injury, stretching, foot

Recently I have started a program to strengthen(and learning to activate) specific muscles relating to overpronation(abductor hallucis, flexor digitorum brevis etc.).

After a few weeks I'm now able to activate and control these muscle but unfortunately only for <1-2 sec before the muscle/s contracts(hurts a bit) which forces me to stretch it out. This is substantially seen in the abductor hallucis muscle which forces the big toe to spread out before I align it to the 'normal'(not normal) position.

Is this normal? Do I need to incorporate stretch? Or will it go over over time?

Comment: sort of related: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22201/cramping-in-the-soles-of-my-feet-during-certain-stretches

Comment: Thanks. I believe this is a different matter. It is not during stretches the cramping occurs,it is simply by activating the 'newly' found muscles in this case.